# wt: Application closing when Website is starting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crash, wt

I need help with my Wt Project. Im using Wt 3 in Visual Studio 19.Everything is working fine in the Debug mode of Vs 19 but when i try to open the .exe without Visual Studio than the application is just closing when the website is starting. Its like a break point i also tried it with the default hello world code but its just not working. Ive linked everything and im using x64 and release mode in the Debug settings.

btw i also tried it on the latest version and its still happening

Can someone pls help me, if you need any more information, than just ask me what you need.

Comment: Add lots of logging to a file. Makes it much easier to track problems and pinpointing when and where possible crashes or other abnormal exits might occur.

Comment: Are the Wt libraries in your path (or same folder as the executable)?